# Publish Already built Mac Applications (.app) on HomeBrew

Tags: macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask, .app

I have built some apps (.app) using Automator on my Mac, is there a way to upload them on Homebrew?

This away other people could download my apps using

`brew install --cask <name>`

I read the guide but I haven't understood if it is possible, I think I should upload them on github, but I don't know how.